# Could someone solve the following syntax error, please?

Tags: python

Note: I am not a regular user of Python.

The following has been identified as a syntax error, and while it may seem somewhat basic or trivial, I cannot for the life of me solve the error.

```
{'key': value for (key, value) in vars()[x]}
```

I also entered it into the IDLE shell, and the following is the received response.

```
>>> x = input('')
1
>>> vars()[x]=[1,2,3]
>>> myDict = {'key': value for (key, value) in vars()[x]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    myDict = {'key': value for (key, value) in vars()[x]}
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    myDict = {'key': value for (key, value) in vars()[x]}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing lists and dictionary here, and it is somewhat unclear what you actually want to achieve. Could you please extend your code example, and give a full example with expected input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a single `int` element rather than a list or dictionary. The following should give you a better idea.

```
vars = {'key':'value'}
for key, value in vars.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

This may suit you better (even though it's counter intuitive really):

```
vars = [1, 2, 3]
d = {'key':'value'}
for value in vars:
    d['key'] = value
print d
```

Output: `{'key': 3}`

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html):

> exception TypeError
>   Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.